# Creating new state array versus mutating previous state in useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Reading questions about `useState` hook I was thinking about `setState`. I'm always using intentionally the `setState` with the callback option to access the previous state and have all the elements for example in an array.

So I have made a quick example for representation in a functional component:

```
const [elems, setElems] = useState([]);

const addElemsMutate = (count) => {
  const newArray = [...elems];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    newArray.push(i);
  }
  setElems(newArray);
};

const addElemsUsePreviousState = (count) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    setElems(previousElems => [...previousElems, i]);
  }
}

return <>
    <button onClick={() => addElemsMutate(10)}>addElemsMutate</button>
    <button onClick={() => addElemsUsePreviousState(10)}>addElemsUsePreviousState</button>
    {elems.map((e, index) => <span key={index}>{e}</span>)}
</>
```

**Question**

I understand the `setState` is **asynchronous**, **enqueues changes** and it **should not be directly mutated** as the [documentation states](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

The result form both of the actions look the same on the UI. So my question is about what I have in `addElemsMutate` function:

1. Is that considered a bad practice?
2. What is the downside if I'm using still that option if there is any?

Thanks!

Comment: ehm, your `addElemsMutate` does NOT mutate `elems`, it mutates a copy of the array. for the most common problem regarding READING the immutable `elems`, see  [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1176601)

Comment: @Aprillion That's my silly mistake with that function's naming. Anyway thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot going on here that may not be intentional:

- As mentioned in a comment, `addElemsMutate()` doesn't actually mutate the state.
- `addElemsUsePreviousState()` enqueues `count` state changes instead of the single one dispatched by `addElemsMutate()`.

You can combine the callback form of `useState()` with `useCallback()` as a small performance optimization.

```
const addElemsCallback = useCallback(count => {
    setElems(elems => {
        const newElems = [...elems];
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            newElems.push(i);
        }
        return newElems;
    });
}, [setElems]);
```

Since `setElems` never changes, neither does `addElemsCallback`, and it's the only thing you need to pass as a dependency.

Comment: `useCallback` is a performance optimization, but it will neither `ensure changes happen correctly` nor `avoid unnecessary DOM manipulation`: 1. DOM `click` event is attached to `document` by `react-dom`, no DOM manipulations needed for swapping synthetic event handlers.. 2. the `<button>`s that are recreated are React elements, not DOM elements. 3. `useCallback` does not influence number of re-renders of the current component, it can influence whether `useEffect(..., [callback])` is executed after a render + if passed as a prop, it can influence re-render of memoized children

Comment: @Aprillion Thanks, I haven't had as much time to dig into the internals as I'd like. I've updated the answer to address your points. Do you bother with `useCallback()` often?

Comment: I almost never use `useCallback`, since functions that are needed inside `useEffect` can be defined inside it and I don't create many memoized components that take a function as a prop

Comment: also just noticed, your `setState` is undefined (based on question code), did you mean `setElems(elems => { ... return newElems; })`?

Comment: @Aprillion Yes, another good catch. Thanks for being my IDE! :)

Answer (score 0):

React best practices for changing states is to copy the current state into a new variable, make the changes there, and then change the state (as you have done so in your example).

This is because, when you change the state directly, instead of deep copying what the previous state was, you run into issues with references, which can leave some hard to find bugs.

Comment: it's not clear whether you are endorsing `addElemsMutate` or `addElemsUsePreviousState`